# prove that for any $\alpha \geq \frac{\Pi }{2}$ the inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$\int_{\frac{\Pi }{2}}^{\alpha }{\frac{\cos x}{x}}\leq 0$

it seems easy, maybe you need to apply the average theorem, please tell me

Comment: If you want to use LaTeX commands here, try surrounding the code with `$` signs for inline maths or `$$` for centre-aligned mathematics.

Comment: Use MathJax & show your own efforts to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here is that the graph of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ consists of "humps" with monotone decreasing areas, alternating above and below the $x$-axis. As you add up the areas of these humps (including stopping in the middle of a hump), you will never recover the negative area of the initial hump under $[\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$. There are parallels to be drawn here between this and the proof of Leibniz' Alternating Series Test.

To prove this formally, I suggest defining a function $f$ such that $f(x) \ge \frac{\cos x}{x}$, which is easier to integrate, and for which $\int_{\pi/2}^\alpha f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \le 0$. For each integer $n \ge 1$, define
\begin{align*} f(x) &= \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi}\cos(x) &\text{for } x \in \left[ \frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}, \frac{(4n + 1)\pi}{2}\right).\end{align*}
Then I claim $f(x) \ge \frac{\cos x}{x}$ for all $x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$. Note that, given any $x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $x \in \left[ \frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}, \frac{(4n + 1)\pi}{2}\right)$ for some $n$. If we also have $x \le \frac{(4n - 1)\pi}{2}$, then $\cos x \le 0$, hence
$$x \in \left[ \frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}, \frac{(4n - 1)\pi}{2}\right] \implies \frac{1}{x} \ge \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi} \text{ and } \cos x \le 0 \implies \frac{\cos x}{x} \le f(x).$$
On the other hand, if $x > \frac{(4n - 1)\pi}{2}$, then $\cos x > 0$, hence
$$x \in \left( \frac{(4n - 1)\pi}{2}, \frac{(4n + 1)\pi}{2}\right) \implies \frac{1}{x} \le \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi} \text{ and } \cos x > 0 \implies \frac{\cos x}{x} \le f(x).$$

Now, we simply need to show $\int_{\pi/2}^\alpha f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \le 0$. Note that, for all integers $n \ge 1$,
$$\int_{\frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}}^{\frac{(4n + 3)\pi}{2}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0.$$
So, find the $n$ corresponding to $\alpha$, i.e. so that $\left[ \frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}, \frac{(4n + 1)\pi}{2}\right)$. We therefore have
\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\alpha f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x &= \int_{\frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}}^\alpha f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi} \int_{\frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}}^\alpha \cos x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi} \left[\sin \alpha - \sin\left(\frac{(4n - 3)\pi}{2}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{2}{(4n - 1)\pi} (\sin \alpha - 1) \le 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\alpha \frac{\cos x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \le \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^\alpha f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \le 0.$$